# Toggled menu is showing behind an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am working on a navigation bar setup and image slider. I combined the code for both as I was initially working on them in different files. Everything is working properly, except when the browser window is resized to show the mobile menu the menu will not show when you click on the menu button. The menu is displaying because it can be seen when the images transition.

I have added z-index to everything I can think of to try and over-lay the menu over top of the image slider, but it does not seem to help.

How can I get the menu to appear over the image slider?

To see this live, please go here: http://realtorcatch.com/slider2

Here is all of the code:

The CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0;
background: #F5F6F8;
}
*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sliderWrapp {
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    /*padding: 30px 10px;*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDE0E7;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
}
#sliderWrapp > div {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*-----Start of code for the header-----*/
.header {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    /*background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0);*/
    height: 80px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    z-index: 999;
}
.header_wrap {
    margin: 0 15%;
}
.logo {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
}
.nav_list {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333;
    /*background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0);*/
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
}
.nav_list > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 25px 15px;
}
.nav_list > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #FFF;
}

    @media screen and (max-width:640px) {
        body {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .header_wrap {
            margin: 0 5%;
        }
        .nav_list {
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            margin-top: 60px;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 999;
        }
        .nav_list > li {
            display: block;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
            z-index: 999;
        }
        /*.nav_list > li > a {
            width: 100%;
        }*/
        .nav-btn {
            display: block;
            background-color: #333;
            color: #FFF;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            text-align: right;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
        .nav-btn:before {
            /*content: url('icons/mobile_menu_bttn.png');*/
            background-image: url('icons/mobile_menu_bttn.png');
            background-size: 28px 28px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            width: 28px;
            height: 28px;
            content:"";
            display: block;
            float: right;
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="sliderWrapp">
<header class="header">
    <div class="header_wrap">
        <div class="logo">Garbrandt Construction</div>
        <nav>
            <span class="nav-btn"></span>
            <ul class="nav_list">
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
    <!-- Start cssSlider -->
    <!-- Generated by cssSlider.com 2.1 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssslider_files/csss_engine1/style.css">
    <!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="cssslider_files/csss_engine1/ie.css"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="cssslider_files/csss_engine1/ie.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cssslider_files/csss_engine1/gestures.js"></script> <div class='csslider1 autoplay '>
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_slide1_0' type="radio" class='cs_anchor slide' >
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_slide1_1' type="radio" class='cs_anchor slide' >
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_slide1_2' type="radio" class='cs_anchor slide' >
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_play1' type="radio" class='cs_anchor' checked>
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_pause1_0' type="radio" class='cs_anchor pause'>
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_pause1_1' type="radio" class='cs_anchor pause'>
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_pause1_2' type="radio" class='cs_anchor pause'>
    <ul>
        <li class="cs_skeleton"><img src="cssslider_files/csss_images1/subway.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></li>
        <li class='num0 img slide'> <img src='cssslider_files/csss_images1/subway.jpg' alt='subway' title='subway' /></li>
        <li class='num1 img slide'> <img src='cssslider_files/csss_images1/beach.jpg' alt='beach' title='beach' /></li>
        <li class='num2 img slide'> <img src='cssslider_files/csss_images1/space.jpg' alt='space' title='space' /></li>
    </ul><div class="cs_engine"><a href="http://cssslider.com">cssslider.com</a> by cssSlider.com v2.1</div>
    <div class='cs_description'>
        <label class='num0'><span class="cs_title"><span class="cs_wrapper">subway</span></span></label>
        <label class='num1'><span class="cs_title"><span class="cs_wrapper">beach</span></span></label>
        <label class='num2'><span class="cs_title"><span class="cs_wrapper">space</span></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class='cs_play_pause'>
        <label class='cs_play' for='cs_play1'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
        <label class='cs_pause num0' for='cs_pause1_0'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
        <label class='cs_pause num1' for='cs_pause1_1'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
        <label class='cs_pause num2' for='cs_pause1_2'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
        </div>
    <div class='cs_arrowprev'>
        <label class='num0' for='cs_slide1_0'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
        <label class='num1' for='cs_slide1_1'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
        <label class='num2' for='cs_slide1_2'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class='cs_arrownext'>
        <label class='num0' for='cs_slide1_0'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
        <label class='num1' for='cs_slide1_1'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
        <label class='num2' for='cs_slide1_2'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class='cs_bullets'>
        <label class='num0' for='cs_slide1_0'> <span class='cs_point'></span>
            <span class='cs_thumb'><img src='cssslider_files/csss_tooltips1/subway.jpg' alt='subway' title='subway' /></span></label>
        <label class='num1' for='cs_slide1_1'> <span class='cs_point'></span>
            <span class='cs_thumb'><img src='cssslider_files/csss_tooltips1/beach.jpg' alt='beach' title='beach' /></span></label>
        <label class='num2' for='cs_slide1_2'> <span class='cs_point'></span>
            <span class='cs_thumb'><img src='cssslider_files/csss_tooltips1/space.jpg' alt='space' title='space' /></span></label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End cssSlider -->
```

Jquery for the mobile menu.

```
$('span.nav-btn').click(function () {
    $('ul.nav_list').slideToggle(500);
})
$(window).resize(function (){
    if ( $(window).width() > 640 ) {
        $('ul.nav_list').removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I finally figured it out. I added `position: relative;` to my mobile media queries' `.nav_list` with the z-index and it works perfectly.

Comment: too bad, I was so happy to see I could help you again today! :) Great work you are doing

Comment: @AndrewAdam I appreciate it!